# Failed to parse the JSON document

Tags: json, groovy

I am getting a "Failed to parse the JSON document" error along with another error: "Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line:" that I can't figure out.

CODE:

```
@Test
public void givenData() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

    Response returnGivenData = given().
    param("location", "-33.8670522,151.195736").
    param("radius", "500").
    param("key", "AIzaSyBde6fW-IAx1j-J5TqNOwmvx-_QPHozqRY").
    when().
    get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
    then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().
    contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
    body("results[0].name", equalTo("Sydney")).and().
    body("results[0].place_id", equalTo("ChIJP3Sa8ziYEmsRUKgyFmh9AQM")).and().
    header("Server", "pablo").
    extract().
    response();
    JsonPath responseJson = ReusableMethods.convertRawDataToJson(returnGivenData);

    int count = responseJson.get("results.size()"); //ERROR LINE
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

ERROR:

```
io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:930)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:895)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:975)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:201)
    at Demo.DemoGivenData2.givenData(DemoGivenData2.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'i', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:85)
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:893)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:928)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Sure your endpoint is returning json? That appears to start with an `i` which cannot be json

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand. What is starting with an "i"?

Comment: _"Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'i'"_ <- from the error you posted in your question

Comment: Your jsonpath string is wrong it should be like "$.results[0].place_id"

Answer (score 4):

I ran into same Json Exception. I found that it occurred because Json Path was not getting proper input to parse. In my case input to JsonPath was the response coming from rest assured given(), when() and then() after sending post request to a rest api and it was null. So would suggest to put logs on returnGivenData and check if it is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

use .asString() methode after response().
please make sure you are using .asString() methode inplace of .tostring() and your JSONPath is correct

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue and found that I was initializing the string before the line where `RestAssured.baseURI = "http://....";` I fixed it.

However, in your case, I believe you can use
`responseJson.getInt("results.size()")`
instead of
`get("results.size()");` in the error line.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`asString()` instead of `toString()`

I had the same and it was fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Intellij as IDE and for me "extract().asString()" worked, I had appended "toString()" earlier which was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.extract().response().asString();` instead of `.toString()`
works for me when caught with a similar error

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me.

In my case, the endpoint which I was passing inside get() method as an argument didn't consist of BASE_URL. I observed that Response of RestAssured.given()... expects *BASE_URL + endpoint* as the argument in get() method. Even baseUri() method is not required for given() in this case.